# Connecting to Zookeeper via SSH port forwarding

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I can connect locally to my Zookeeper instance:

[zookeeperServer]# zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181

However if I try to do it via SSH forwarded port, it initially connects, but then immediately gets disconnected:

[myLaptop]# ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:2181 zookeeperServer

[myLaptop]# zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:1234

```
2014-10-03 15:25:18,989 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:1234):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:1234, initiating session
[zk: 127.0.0.1:1234(CONNECTING) 0] 2014-10-03 15:25:19,836 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:1234):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2014-10-03 15:25:21,923 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:1234):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:1234. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-10-03 15:25:21,924 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:1234):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:1234, initiating session
2014-10-03 15:25:22,352 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:1234):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1098] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

.....
the previous 3 lines (Opening socket, Socket connection established, Unable to read additional data) start repeating
.....

Is there anything else (some hostnames etc.) that Zookeeper is dependent on, and that needs to be configured so that connection to Zookeeper works over forwarded port?

Comment: Maybe if you append "-v" to ssh it would give you some hint about what's happening with the tunnel.